# MVC3 Return View By Default

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, default

Basically, I was wondering if anyone knows of a way that you can set up MVC3 in a way that it will first look for an action, and if none exists, it will automatically return the view at that location. Otherwise each time I make a page, I will have to rebuild it after adding the action.

It isn't something that's stopping the project from working nor is it an issue, it would just be a very nice thing to include in the code to help with speed of testing more than anything.

EDIT:

Just for clarity purposes, this is what I do every time I create a view that doesn't have any logic inside it:

```
public ActionResult ActionX()
{
    return View();
}
```

Sometimes I will want some logic inside the action, but majority of the time for blank pages I will just want the above code.

I would like it if there was any way to always return the above code for every Controller/Action combination, UNLESS I have already made an action, then it should use the Action that I have specified.

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: I don´t know what you want excactly. I see many different things in your question, everything is possible. Please give more informations.

Comment: @dknaack Editied pose, see if that helps. Ask again if you need more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not altogether sure how useful this will be (or whether its really a good idea) but I guess if you have pages which are purely static content (but maybe use a layout or something so you can't use static html) it could be useful

This is how it could be done though anyway (as a base class, but it doesn't have to be)

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        return View();
    }

    protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
    {
        return new DefaultActionInvoker();
    }

    private class DefaultActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
    {
        protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
        {
            var actionDescriptor = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);

            if (actionDescriptor == null)
                actionDescriptor = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, "Default");

            return actionDescriptor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a shot and give any feedback on it.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a bunch for this. Was twiddling my thumbs wondering what to do about it. Thanks again!

Comment: Promise me you'll use IoC to create your controllers (and set the custom action invoker) instead of the base class if you take this approach!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a single action for this. This will look for a view with the specified name and return a 404 if it doesn't exist.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Page(string page)
    {
        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, page, null);

        if (result == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(page);
    }
```

Then make your default route fall back to this:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "{page}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Page" });
```

So a request to http://yoursite.com/somepage will invoke Page("somepage")